# How to use Common.Logging.Log4Net to log all messages grouped

Tags: c#, log4net

So I am using Common.Logging.Log4Net for logging purposes, but since the code is multithreaded, often messages get mixed up, eg:

message from thread 1
message from thread 2
message from thread 1
message from thread 1
message from thread 2

In order to avoid this, we are trying to get all messages together and we print them all when the execution finishes. For that we basically have a list of Action delegates and each contains the log line, eg:

```
            Log.DebugFormat("Handling...");
```

But this unfortunately does not solve any issue, because when we write back to the log, messages still get mixed, since all we do is a foreach on the list and execute the delegates. So is there any way to get all the messages written at once?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for some sort of transaction logging.  By nature, application logging is sequential.

A couple of options I can think of off-hand:

- Log the thread id.  Use a more appropriate log analyzer when reviewing the output. Excel works fine if you're using CSV or other common format.  When you're interested in a certain thread's actions, filter on the thread id.  I'd try this route first.
- Log each thread to a separate file. I've seen Microsoft do this on occasion. Might work ok.  Would have to uniquely identify each file somehow.  Guessing log4net can handle that.